# What is the difference between GL_POINTS and GL_POINT

Tags: c, opengl

When I hover over to GL_POINTS, it shows

`#define GL_POINTS 0x0000`

and it falls under the category of primitives

Similarly, GL_POINT falls under 'polygons' category and 
shows the descritption:

`#define GL_POINT 0x1B00`

there is no clear documentation available for GL_POINT, though there is for GL_POINTS (reference: docs.gl)

Similarly, replacing either doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `GL_POINTS` is a primitive type: it defines how vertices are grouped together. It is the `mode` parameter in commands such as `glDrawArrays`, `glDrawElements`, and other `glDraw...`
- `GL_POINT` is a rendering mode for polygons using in `glPolygonMode`. Normally, triangles are rasterized onto the framebuffer, filling the space between vertices. If one wishes to render only triangles' vertices or edges, this can be achieved by `glPolygonMode(GL_POINT)` or `glPolygonMode(GL_LINE)`, respectively.

Comment: Can you suggest a good site to learn these things? I used docs.gl, but it isn't that good. And the other sites I tried provide incomplete documentation

Comment: @kesarling `docs.gl` is the best online reference available, but it is still just a reference. I'd suggest finding some fairly modern tutorials (not books - those are usually outdated, to my experience). A good start would be http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/index.html. For a solid & deep resource, have a look at https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Main_Page, e.g. the `Rendering Pipeline` section.

Comment: Thank a lot sir :)

Comment: @kesarling I may be wrong, but I believe they don't have any special meaning: just standardized constant values for programmers & OpenGL implementations to use.

Comment: @kesarling For a good reason: the actual values should be irrelevant to you. They are included in all OpenGL implementation headers (`GL.h` or similar), so that you don't write `glPolygonMode(0x1B00)`, but `glPolygonMode(GL_POINT)`.